# If I had 2xUSBA @2.4A/ea. but only 4A max output from 21W solar panel, would joining the usb cable leads together give me one safe a 5v/4A output?

Tags: usb, solar-energy, 5v, powerbanks

Mission-Solar fast charge? If I had a 21W solar panel with 2 USBA/2.4A or 4A max outs, could I simply strip and match leads to form one USBC input to a USBC input on a Poweradd PD 30W Power bank and charge at 20W , and would combining the leads from the 2 usba outputs cause any adverse effects to the circuit?

Comment: 5V at 4A is already 20W so you're not going to get anything more by combining multiple outputs. And there are MPPT chargers that get the maximum output from solar panels but we've no idea what low cost means to you, that would make it a shopping question anyway.

Comment: _”in-line, device to insure maximum power transfer from the solar panel?”_ It’s called an MPPT.

Comment: The object was not to magically generate more power by combining wires. The goal was stated clearly,ie, to join the output leads together into one usbc male to input into the usbc 'PD' female terminal of the power bar without damaging either component. Furthermore, Winny, if you were familiar with the  items listed you could form a reasonable idea of what would be frugal. ... Ty for the MPPT refer. [Edited by moderator]

Comment: Without knowing the specific details about the voltage regulators and other devices in the chain, we can't conclude paralleling outputs is safe, effective, or functional. Seeing datasheets and/or circuit diagrams would be very helpful, but without that detail, my first instinct would be that paralleling the outputs is infeasible without your own circuitry to properly combine them.

Answer (score 0):

You can "quite possibly" combine two USBA outputs safely.
Damage is unlikely to occur, but this is never 100% certain.

You cannot supply a USBC input at high current froim USBA without providing a suitable USBC interface unit. These are available at very reasonable prices.

For completeness: You cannot combine two USBC outputs together effectively except by using a module designed for this purpose. USBC negotiates it's voltage and maximum current levels via a digital protocol and just paralleling two outputs would lead to a wholly undefined result. Damage could conceivably occur if one supply was confused enough to negotiate a > 5V output, but this seems very unlikely.

As Finbarr notes, if you have a 4A output then its power level approximately matches the panel input and just using that will probably achieve as good a result as you can expect.

A solat input USBC output solar power supply supplied with a PV panel of about or slightly less than the maximum load will quite likely achieve something like MPPT charging as the panel voltage will load down if excess current is drawn. In low light conditions where panel output is significantly lower the result depends on how smart the designers were in anticipating this very common situation.

It is always an extremely good idea to provide links to products used - in this case both the PV to USBA unit and the target USBC device.